# Different logging in console and report file

Tags: karate

I am using Karate for my 100+ API tests.

Off late, I am seeing that the results/logging that is supposed to be printed in the console is getting hanged/not printing and also the reports are not generated (especially: `karate-tags.html, karate-timeline.html,` and `karate-summary.html`). It happens when the logging level is INFO / DEBUG but works with ERROR.

I initially thought, not to print everything but only the ERROR in the console and all debug stuff in the report file. So, I modified the `logback-test.xml` to below but the console still printing all debug messages and as a result, it is getting hanged.

```
<logger name="com.intuit" level="DEBUG"/>
   
    <root level="debug">
        <!-- <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> -->
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <!-- <appender-ref ref="FILE" /> -->
    </root>
```

How to achieve this if it is possible? or how to approach the issue when the above approach is not feasible?

*Running env:*
Windows10, i7 with 32GB RAM, VisualStudioCode, karate.version: 1.1.0.RC2, Java 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where the best thing is for you to troubleshoot or profile your tests and help us fix any memory-usage issues. There have been such issues in the past, and can certainly be there now.

One thing, please try with 1.1.0.RC4 if you are not already. It may have some improvements.

I also think having two `root` sections may be wrong, but please refer to logback documentation if needed.

Comment: `ThresholdFilter` is all I am looking for, thank you @Peter